# Не отображается балун одиночных меток на яндекс.карт

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Вывожу метки на карте при помощи objectManager. Не открывается при клике балун одиночных меток. При клике на сгруппированные балун отображается нормально. Вот вызов карты:

```
var myMap,
    geoObjects,
    objectManager,
    arr_check = [];

ymaps.ready(init);
        function init()
        {
            myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center: [".$last_gps."],
                    zoom: 14,
                    type: 'yandex#satellite'
                }, {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'

                });
                objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
                    clusterize: true,
                    gridSize: 32,
                    clusterDisableClickZoom: true
                });
                objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#grayDotIcon');
                objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#grayClusterIcons');
                myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'panel_json.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {arrp:arr_check}
                }).done(function(data) {
                    objectManager.add(data);
                    geoObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(data)
                            .applyBoundsToMap(myMap, {
                                checkZoomRange: true
                            });
                });

                myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

        };
```

JSON принимаю такого типа:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": "55.831903, 37.411961"
        },
        "properties": {
            "balloonContent": "<a href=\'more.php?id=1\'>Описание</a>",
            "hintContent": "Описание",
            "clusterCaption": "Описание"
        },
        "options": {
            "preset": "islands#icon",
            "iconColor": "#00AA00"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Пример брал здесь https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данных для ObjectManager должны быть уникальные поля id для каждого геообъекта.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      ...
    },{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Также координаты правильно писать массивом из двух элементов:

```
"coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/10mqLvfw/

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Да, и координаты у меня в коде указаны массивом. Это здесь в вопросе я неправильно прописал.